# How to get a list of algorithms supported by TPM

Tags: windows, tpm

On linux i can use tpm2_getcap tool to get list of encryption algorithms like this:

> tpm2_getcap algorithms

Is there something similar on Windows? I only found "Get-TpmSupportedFeature" in powershell, but it is not what i wanted.

Comment: FWIW, I'm looking for exactly the same answer; there are two standard NCrypt calls in Windows, NCryptEnumAlgorithms and NCryptIsAlgSupported, but neither returns any results at all for the TPM I have in my machine. Also, these are low level programming calls, not command line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862767/how-to-encrypt-bytes-using-the-tpm-trusted-platform-module