# Store and retrieve a symmetric AES key in the TPM on windows

Tags: c#, windows, tpm

I need to store and retrieve a symmetric AES key securely using the TPM on a windows machine. The key will be used in a windows application running on the same machine. Each time the application runs it will do the following:

- Check the TPM for the AES key
- If there is no key present, generate the key and store it in the TPM
- If there is a key in the TPM, use it

Is storing the key in an NV (Non Volatile) Index a reasonable way to do this? Are there better alternatives using the TPM?

Comment: Surprisingly nontrivial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862767/how-to-encrypt-bytes-using-the-tpm-trusted-platform-module

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/procedure-for-storing-a-session-key might be a good start.